# Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool?' and 'bool?'

Tags: c#, logical-operators

I want to check if one of two strings contains a partial string. 
Knowing that firstString or secondString can be null, I tried the following:

```
 string firstString= getValue();
 string secondString= getValue();

 if (firstString?.Contains("1") || secondString?.Contains("1"))
   {
     //logic
   }
```

I am getting a compile time error mentioning that:

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool?' and
>   'bool?'

Seems like result of String?.Contains("1") is nullable boolean.

This error actually does make sense to me because running time might face:

```
{null||true, null||false, null||null, etc..}
```

What is the best way to override this error? can I avoid writing two nested ifs?

Comment: Operations on a nullable value have to be nullable themselves. The nullable form of a `bool` or any other value type *is* Nullable<ThatType>`.

Comment: I'd prefer `(firstString ?? "").Contains("1")` myself, to make it clear what my intended semantics are when there is no string. (If anyone wants to give me grief about "performance" because of this super-expensive operation on an empty string -- please don't.)

Comment: If you do not need short-circuit behavior of `||`, then you can use `|` instead.

Comment: @PetSerAl - yes, that does shed some light on the deeper problem. But you wouldn't get away with the `bool?` result in the `if()`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It depends how you want to evaluate a `null` value: as `true` or `false`. I am used to false.

If so, you can use the null-coalescing operator:

```
(firstString?.Contains("1") ?? false) || (secondString?.Contains("1") ?? false)
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be a quite naive way of doing, but you can avoid nesting of if condition, by checking the string for empty or null with "&&" operator, as sample condition below.

```
if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstString) && firstString.Contains("1")) || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondString) && secondString.Contains("1")))
{
                //logic
}
```